# Validate short dates based on culture information

Tags: c#-3.0

I have

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

 CultureInfo ci1 = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); // German

 CultureInfo ci2 = new CultureInfo("fr-FR"); // French



Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d", ci1)); // output: 15.11.2010

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d", ci2)); // output : 15/11/2010
```

Now suppose, the user has entered 11/15/2010 when the Culture is German or French in which case it is invalid.

Is there any way to validate dates based on culture information. I am looking for **short date pattern**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.. It is **DateTime.ParseExact**

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("15.11.2009",cultureinfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern,cultureinfo); 
// will throw error
but  not 

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("15/11/2009",cultureinfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern,cultureinfo);
```

same for anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use System's Convert.ToDateTime function, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=VS.90).aspx for reference.

It will throw an exception if your input date is not valid in the current culture.